# My links got messed up after using .htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wanted my site to go from domain.com/page.php?id=1 to domain.com/page/1

Using `RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1` in .htaccess file works when going directly to domain.com/live/1, but the CSS is all messed up.

For example, instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>` pointing to domain.com/style.css, it is pointing to domain.com/page/style.css

How can I fix this??  :( :(

Edit: Should I start using non-relative links (full path)?

The full .htaccess is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1
```

To solve this issue, I had to put `<base href="http://domain.com/directory/" />`

in the head of my page. The javascript files I had to make absolute paths since different browsers handle the base tag differently.

Comment: post the whole .htaccess. Did you add conditions like `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`  so it only kicks in when is a virtual path?

Comment: I've posted it as an edit up above.

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem. It's because your browser now assumes /page/ is the root where it should start looking for css files etc, Simply put:

```
<base href="/">
```

In your

```
<head>.
```

Your browser will now strt looking for css files etc from the root of your website.

**edit: nvm, messed up formatting because posting from my iPod but I see you resolved the issue already :)**

Comment: Yes I solved this issue, and wanted to give back to the community by providing answer.

Comment: Old question but you saved my life... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I had to put

in the head of my page. The javascript files I had to make absolute paths since different browsers handle the base tag differently.